# I can't use php with SSH on OVH (php7.1)

Tags: php, ssh, symfony4, ovh

Since today, I can't use php with SSH on OVH.
Are you currently experiencing this problem?

For exemple when I use :

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug --no-warmup
```

The answer is :

```
-ovh_ssh: /usr/local/php7.1/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

My environnement configuration is :

**In .bashrc :**

```
alias php='/usr/local/php7.1/bin/php'
```

**In .ovhconfig**

```
app.engine=phpcgi
app.engine.version=7.1
http.firewall=none
environment=production
container.image=stable
```

Could you help me please ?

Steve

Comment: Are you sure PHP7.1 is configured in cli mode?

Comment: I have been experiencing this problem since this morning. I did not change anything before everything worked. It's strange ...

Comment: That's not a Symfony problem. Do you have sufficient permission to search for the PHP executable on your machine?

Comment: @SteveV. I'm having the same issue, too

Comment: @MrDevel, maybe it comes from OVH ..

Comment: @Louis-MarieMatthews two years ago yes but since Friday i can't ... However I have not changed anything.

Comment: @MrDevel my problem is solved. A person from the OVH community solved my problem. I asked him to tell me more about where the problem came from. I will share his answer with you.

Comment: @SteveV. It would be great! I'm still having the issue and none of the support is able to help me

Comment: @SteveV. Please let me know asa that I'm becoming crazy with this issue :( Thank you so much

Comment: @MrDevel, a person of OVH told me: that there was a configuration problem on your account that impacted your SSH access.

You can find his answer here :
https://community.ovh.com/t/erreur-usr-local-php7-1-bin-php-depuis-ssh/6602/5